# Blob database, extremely dynamic database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, nosql

I am helping one of my professors out by doing a special course where I am to create a piece of software for him. But due to the nature of being a student, can my professor not count on me being there for long, to keep the software up to date, and he is afraid what he will be unable to find a student who can take over after me.

My task is to design a backend API for a tool (This is a tool where you can enter data, and set up relations between data). But because of the above reason do he wish for me to design the database so dynamically that he can add new field to “areas” (What we normally would call a table when doing semantic database), and he even will be able to add new areas.

Now this is not set in stone, I have to argue between different approaches before I select one, so I can go with a normal semantic database if I can argue for it.

My main problem is that I have no experience created what I have been told is called a “blob database”, and when I Google it can I only find “blog database”. 
Does anyone have expense with that, and can give me or point me to some information on this topic? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Blob is usually shorthand for binary large object, and is a datatype in most RDBM's.  It's frequently used to store large objects (images, files, etc) in the database.

Comment: @MichaelGardner That i know :D i was just told that a database of this type of design is also called a Blob database, not saying that i am right!

Comment: Well, I've worked with databases for 10+ years and have never heard that term before...almost sounds like a 10-20 year old buzz word.  Regardless, good luck..I'll delete my comment shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for a key/value store, possibly with secondary indexes. Take a look at Redis for example.